# R Barplot: Re-Order X-Axis Labels

Tags: r, formatting, bar-chart

I have created a Barplot that displays the number of incidents per hour. However, it looks like R sorts the X-Axis labels as characters and not as numeric. I would like have my X-Axis ordered as 0, 1,2,3,4,5,..., 23. Is there anyway I can explicitly specify the order?

**Update**: More generally, if I want a specific order, what do I need to do? I have not found any options for the barplot() function in the documentation that allows to specify explicitly the order of the labels of the barplot.

```
# 5. Bar Plot for the Time (Hour) of Incidents
barplot(xtabs(~sample$Time), 
        main="Number of Incidents per Time Slot", 
        ylab="Frequency",
        col=rainbow(nlevels(as.factor(sample$Time))),
        las=2,
        # cex.lab=0.50 This is for the x-axis Label,
        cex.names = 0.80
)
```

[image]

Comment: Change it to `xtabs(~as.numeric(sample$Time))`

Comment: Thanks, this works for this graph, but more generally if I want a specific order... Let's say for Days... I want Sunday, Monday....

Comment: You need to specify the levels of your factor in the order you desire - `barplot(table(factor(1:3, levels=c(2,1,3))))`